# Prevent line break at one specific spot

Tags: line-breaking

I have

```
\myDefineTerm{longFunctionName}($\pi$)....
```

and want to tell LaTeX not to break the line just before the open bracket. Is there something like `~` that pretent a line break, but does not cause a horizontal space?

Note: `\mbox` is not helpful, since I want to allow hyphenation of longFunctionName.

Comment: @administrators: actually a pretty stupid question. Feel free to delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\myDefineTerm{longFunctionName}\nolinebreak($\pi$)
```